Do we need to wrap update_all operations with transaction block in rails?
I will be running a cron job, for my application. The task for this cron job is to reset values for a column in my rails application subscription table. I am wondering if we need to wrap this Subscription.update_all() operation with a transaction block or not?
Like what happens if for some unknown reason the update_all operation fails in the middle. Will the changes already done persist? Or will everything be back to original state like a transaction?

I read somewhere that update_all constructs a single SQL update statement and sends it directly to the database. And hence, I think we should not be needing a transaction block. Not sure though!

I think this may be dependent on which database you use.  If you use Postgresql you should be good.

@PiyushSinghania you are correct about update_all: "This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database." so any failure would result in a failure of the entire statement.

@BenTrewern it does not. On any database update_all creates a single query. Postgres is in no way different when it comes to this.

upsert_all makes everything in one query

@max You are right, it is one query, but if you ran this on MySQL using myisam engine and it had an error half way through the update would it roll back all the records?
